# How do I setup argument in Rscripts with name

Tags: r, batch-file, command-line

I want to execute an R script via command line parsing arguments to it. I know this can be done like this:
Rscript script.R arg1 arg2, and that the arguments can be read in the R script as:

`args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)`
`input1 = args[1]`
`input2 = args[2]`

but I was wondering: is there a way to define flags (e.g., --input) those arguments can be provided with, so that I do not have to worry about the order in which I provide them? I have looked around quite a while, but was not able to find a way.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: http://tuxette.nathalievilla.org/?p=1696

Answer (score 0):

Use the library optArgs. It gives you all functionality you need.
You can add options via command:

```
 add_option()
```

and parse arguments with:

```
parse_args()
```

See [optparse](https://github.com/trevorld/r-optparse) for more details.